# Elastic Beanstalk, Nginx configuration with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application working on Elastic Beanstalk. This application exports two ports of the Docker container. Nginx only takes the first one, so I have to change the configuration to add another one.

Following [this post](https://flynn.gg/blog/multiple-ports-docker-elasticbeanstalk/) and [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.htm) I'm trying to extend nginx configuration to add another upstream, so I have created further file to do that:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/api-port.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |

      upstream docker {
        server 172.17.0.2:4003;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
          listen 4003;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }
          access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
          proxy_pass            http://docker;
          proxy_http_version    1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection        $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }
```

This file is deployed within the folder `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/api-port.conf` and copied to EC2 instance, but it is not working and it is not copied to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` either.

Any idea about what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move the file from `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/api-port.conf` to `.ebextensions/api-port.config`. That should fix the file not copied to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`